# Django admin/ ViewDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I checked the other questions on here like this one, but couldn't get an accurate answer that would solve my problem. When i run the dev server with `python manage.py runserver` I get the following     `

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.6.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'firstapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py"   in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,  **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  215.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  194.                                            current_app=self.name):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  503.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in app_dict
  329.             self._populate()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  303.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern,     pattern.default_args))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  230.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  32.         result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  118.                         (lookup_view, mod_name))

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /admin/
Exception Value: Could not import Chinatown.views. View does not exist in module Chinatown.
```

`

But when i check my other project with which i follow the official django tut I dont have the mentioned views file in the project directory but I am able to see the admin page. Any suggestions why is the error being raised?

Comment: Check for the case of folder or filename.

Comment: What's your INSTALLED_APPS setting and urls.py look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it will be more useful if just copy / paste error log . use:

```
./manage.py runserver --traceback
```

you need to add function in chinatown/views.py say "food"

and a url pattern in project's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^food/$', 'chinatown.views.food'),
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Comment: chinatown/views file doesnt exist and from what it looks like in the other project(the one that has no problem) its not needed..

Comment: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py  it's something wrong with your urls.py . post that too . if not check every {%url ... %}, reverse